# java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to getPixels(), pixel access is not supported on Config#HARDWARE bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, palette

I'm getting the vibrantSwatch color from bitmap using Palette.

To get bitmap from uri before I wrote this code(In API 29 getBitmap has depricated) :

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(),
    Uri.fromFile(ImageModelArrayList.get(position).getImageUri()));
```

Because of deprication I wrote this code now to get bitmap:

```
 ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Uri.fromFile(ImageModelArrayList.get(position).getImageUri()));
            Bitmap bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
```

Now here in this Palette code I'm getting crash(If I use getBitmap no issue. If I use ImageDecoder I'm getting crash):

```
Palette p = createPaletteSync(bitmap);
            Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = p.getDominantSwatch();
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: vibrantSwatch " + vibrantSwatch);
            if (vibrantSwatch != null) {
                holder.constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(vibrantSwatch.getRgb());
            }
```

Error:

```
2020-02-29 12:32:56.722 9865-9865/com.msp.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.msp.project, PID: 9865
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to getPixels(), pixel access is not supported on Config#HARDWARE bitmaps
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkHardware(Bitmap.java:401)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getPixels(Bitmap.java:1760)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 15):

You can copy the bitmap to a mutable one, not ideal but it works:

```
ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source).copy(Bitmap.Config.RGBA_F16, true)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best solution but it worked!

Comment: Use following if you are still getting into exceptions:
ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(mContext.getContentResolver(),selectedImage)).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

Answer (score 12):

In Compose & Coil:

```kotlin
import coil.compose.rememberImagePainter

val imagePainter = rememberImagePainter(
                    data = product.imageUrl,
                    builder = {
                        crossfade(true)
                        placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
                        allowHardware(false) //IMPORTANT!
                    }
                )
```

Comment: allowHardware(false) worked!!

Answer (score 8):

By default `ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap()` returns immutable bitmap. And default allocation for the pixel memory is `HARDWARE` but may switch to `software` in case there is a small image or when `HARDWARE` is incompatible. ([More info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder))

To get a mutable bitmap, you can set `isMutableRequired = true`. But when allocation is `HARDWARE`, bitmaps are **immutable** so first you need to change allocation of decoder.

You can handle this with other `decodeBitmap()` overload with `OnHeaderDecodedListener`.

```
var mutableBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(
                    source,
                    ImageDecoder.OnHeaderDecodedListener { decoder, info, source ->
                        decoder.allocator = ImageDecoder.ALLOCATOR_SOFTWARE
                        decoder.isMutableRequired = true
                    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
```

By

```
ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source, (imageDecoder, imageInfo, source1) -> imageDecoder.setMutableRequired(true));
```